# How can i make an interesting tree trunk without having to sculpt it?

Tags: add-on, sapling-addon

I'm looking for alternatives to the sapling tree or modular tree addons, because I want to have more control over the trunk shape and I want the branches, trunk and roots to be one whole mesh instead of intersecting. Is there a way to achieve such effects without having to manually sculpt it? Because I want to make a lot of similar types of trees with different shapes to populate a forest.
Here is an example image of the type of trunk shape and detail that I'd like to create.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to script this? Or are you asking for a modeling technique?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2emVk-TFaXw
Crack it addon .
It will save your day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know from my expierience with substance designer you can create almost everything with a height-map and a Displacement Modifier. Since blender has the amazing possibility to create stunning procedural textures, I would go with that. Create a few basic trees, with some branches and apply a procedural displacement-map on it, you can create it in the node-editor. The big advantage of procedural textures in blender is to create many different variations by just tweaking a few parameters, in blender you can even use the position of your trees as a driver for different parameters, it's not the easiest thing to do, but it creates a lot of realistic varaitions once you've done the node setup. If you have no expierience with procedural textures, you can watch a few youtube tutorials how tree-barks are made procedural. This is what I found.

https://youtu.be/Rh5gAQLtOls
https://youtu.be/tS3D3cSgRyE
https://www.blendernation.com/2019/03/14/download-procedural-pine-bark-shader/
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/types/procedural/index.html

All the best Marco

Comment: Grazie mille! Sì, diciamo che so le basi perchè ho incominciato ad usare Blender anni fa proprio sperimentando con il displacement procedurale che trovo molto interessante. Comunque ho appena scoperto Speedtree e penso che lo userò per questo progetto perchè mi da proprio il controllo che cercavo, posso anche aggiungere funghi, muschio e licheni sul tronco e poi voglio usare Unreal Engine 4 per il rendering finale in ogni caso, quindi è molto comodo. Il tuo consiglio e i link mi torneranno utili senz'altro nei miei futuri progetti! Grazie ancora! :)

Comment: By the way, I assumed you are italian like me by the name. If you're not, my apologies and here is the english translation of what I wrote:

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, let's say I know the basics because I started using Blender years ago just experimenting with the procedural displacement that I find very interesting. Anyway I just discovered Speedtree and I think I will use it for this project because it gives me the control I was looking for, I can also add mushrooms, moss and lichens on the trunk and then I want to use Unreal Engine 4 for the final rendering in any case, so it is very comfortable. Your advice and links will certainly come in handy in my future projects! Thanks again!

Comment: We cannot use procedural textures with blender .